# c# round to two decimal places to give 25.00

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am puling a number from a database : 25000842
I need to display it as 25.00 (I've already divided by 1000000)

```
            formattedNumber = (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.##");
```

The above always gives 25
If I choose three decimal places it displays 25.001

```
           formattedNumber = Math.Round(num / 1000000D, 3).ToString();
           formattedNumber = Math.Round(num / 1000000D, 2).ToString();
```

The above code return 25.001 or 25
Is there any way I can display 25.00?

Comment: Did you try `formattedNumber = (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.00");`? See https://dotnetfiddle.net/pPIip9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ToString("0.00") to view two decimal places, like this:

```
formattedNumber = (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Format for that

```
var number = 25000842;
var numberDivided = (number / 1000000D);
var formattedNumber = String.Format("{0:0.00}", numberDivided); //25.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var valFromDb = 25000842;
var result = (valFromDb / 1000000D);
var output = Math.Round(result, 2).ToString("0.00");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```